# Bar chart for grouped data in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I want to create bar chart for grouped data in R, but could not find the right code.
In my case I have three different columns with math score, reading score and writing score. Also for all those three columns I want to seperate female and man results. See the photo of the result I want to get.[image]

The data is here https://www.kaggle.com/spscientist/students-performance-in-exams
First of all I need to find the mean of female math,reading and writing results and the mean of men math, reading and writing results and I use for that code like that:

```
dta %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>%   
  summarise(mathmean = mean(math.score), 
            readingmean = mean(reading.score), 
            writingmean = mean(writing.score))
```

But then, how can I do the bar chart like in the picture below?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
# https://www.kaggle.com/spscientist/students-performance-in-exams
input_csv <- file.choose()

# read in the csv file
students_performance <- read_csv(input_csv)


students_performance %>% 
  select(gender, 'writing score', 'reading score', 'math score') %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars('writing score', 'reading score', 'math score'), funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c('writing score', 'reading score', 'math score'),
               names_to = 'type',
               values_to = 'score') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(type, levels = c('writing score', 'reading score', 'math score')), y = score, fill = gender)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(score, digits = 1)), position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -0.2) +
  expand_limits(y = 80) +
  labs(
    title = "Student Performance by Gender",
    x = "Exam Type",
    y = "Mean Score",
    fill = "Gender"
  ) +
    theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I have updated my solution. FYI you can accomplish this by utilizing `theme` as shown in my code.

Comment: Updated my solution.

Comment: It puzzles me that read_csv leaves spaces in column names. That then seems to defeat the attraction of tidyvrse syntax that allows referring to columns in an unquoted manner. (Just an observation, rather than a criticism of the answer.)